# Matplotlib animation not showing image plotted using gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a simple animation of sampled distributions using gridspec by using FuncAnimation.
The program is returning the object without showing the animation:
matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f5f81640a20
I don't know what I am missing in my code. Any comment is welcome, below is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

n = 100

# create the function that will do the plotting, where curr is the current frame
def update(curr):

    # check if animation is at the last frame, and if so, stop the animation a
    if curr == n: 
        a.event_source.stop()
    
    plt.cla()
    bins = 1000
    
    #Practice assignment Understanding Distributions through sampling

    # generate 4 random variables from the random, gamma, exponential, and uniform distributions
    x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, n)
    x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, n)
    x3 = np.random.exponential(2, n)+7
    x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, n)

    #Create a gridspec object
    gs1=gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=1/2, hspace=1/2)

    ax1=plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
    ax1.set_title('Normal Distribution', loc='center')

    ax2=plt.subplot(gs1[0,1])
    ax2.set_title('Gamma Distribution', loc='center')

    ax3=plt.subplot(gs1[1,0])
    ax3.set_title('Exponential Distribution', loc='center')

    ax4=plt.subplot(gs1[1,1])
    ax4.set_title('Uniform Distribution', loc='center')

    fig1.suptitle('Distributions through Sampling',y=1)

    # plot the histograms
    ax1.hist(x1, bins=bins, normed=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')
    ax2.hist(x2, bins=bins, normed=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')
    ax3.hist(x3, bins=bins, normed=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')
    ax4.hist(x4, bins=bins, normed=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')


#Create the figure
fig1=plt.figure(1)
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update, interval=1000)   
plt.show()~~~
```

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook?

Comment: Hi Konqui, I am using jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was your initial mistake exactly, but you shouldn't create a new set of Axes at every iteration. Create your axes once and reuse them in the `update` function. Also, you were never using the parameter passed to `update` anywhere.

I think that's what you wanted

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


# create the function that will do the plotting, where curr is the current frame
def update(curr):
    bins = 1000

    # Practice assignment Understanding Distributions through sampling

    # generate 4 random variables from the random, gamma, exponential, and uniform distributions
    x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, size=curr)
    x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, size=curr)
    x3 = np.random.exponential(2, size=curr) + 7
    x4 = np.random.uniform(14, 20, size=curr)

    for ax in fig1.axes:
        ax.cla()
    # unfortunately, clearing the axes has the unfortunate side-effect of removing the titles
    ax1.set_title('Normal Distribution', loc='center')
    ax2.set_title('Gamma Distribution', loc='center')
    ax3.set_title('Exponential Distribution', loc='center')
    ax4.set_title('Uniform Distribution', loc='center')
    # plot the histograms
    ax1.hist(x1, bins=bins, density=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')
    ax2.hist(x2, bins=bins, density=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')
    ax3.hist(x3, bins=bins, density=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')
    ax4.hist(x4, bins=bins, density=True, alpha=0.5, histtype='stepfilled', color='steelblue', edgecolor='none')


# Create the figure
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
# Create a gridspec object
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=1 / 2, hspace=1 / 2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 1])

fig1.suptitle('Distributions through Sampling', y=1)

a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update, frames=np.arange(100, 10000, 1000, dtype=int), interval=500, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it helped me resolve the issue with the code